# c# data row error from tutorial

Tags: c#, database, dataset

I have been following a tutorial on the internet it can be found at [Add a New Record to the Database](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p10.html). I have code that is identical for input in to a dataset and database, but I get this error

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

here is my full code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con;
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da;
        DataSet ds1;


        int MaxRows = 0;
        int inc = 0;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            ds1 = new DataSet();

            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Kart_Setup;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

            con.Open();

            da.Fill(ds1, "Setup");   
        }

        private void clr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }

        private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder cb;
            cb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder(da);


          DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Setup"].NewRow();

          dRow[1] = FL.Value;
          dRow[2] = FR.Value;
          dRow[3] = RL.Value;
          dRow[4] = RR.Value;

          ds1.Tables["Setup"].Rows.Add(dRow);

          MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
          inc = MaxRows - 1;

          da.Update(ds1, "Setup");

          MessageBox.Show("Setup Added");

          con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks in advance

Comment: Which line is the exception being thrown on? If you're using Visual Studio, you should be able to find this out easily using the exception helper.

Comment: If you could tell us where the exception is thrown, it would be very helpful in solving your problem.

Comment: instead of asking us to hunt ghosts in here why don't you at least tell us which line throws the exception when you step in with the debugger?

Comment: it is thrown on the DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Setup"].NewRow(); line

Comment: @Davide: If he's trying to learn than leave him alone. If he doesn't understand the error, he needs to get some input so we can help him figure it out.

Comment: Looks like the da variable is not initialized.  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da; is just a declaration... You need to do something like  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(.....);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare ds to something... try....

EDIT: Fixed code to add datatable to the dataset.

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable("Setup");
ds1.Tables.Add(dt);
DataRow dRow = ds1.Tables["Setup"].NewRow();
```

Also, be sure to initialize all variables, these look suspicious:

```
MaxRows = MaxRows + 1;
inc = MaxRows - 1;
```

It looks as though these are declared in the class itself, put this outside of the function:

```
public intMaxRows = 0;
public int inc = 0;
```

Also, I do not know what da is supposed to be, but you'll need to instantiate that as well.

Comment: i have tried adding that to my existing code but it didn't work

Comment: look above ... ds1.Tables.Add(dt);

Answer (score 1):

What is da? Is it null?

Have you initialized ds1?

Is FL null?

Is FR null?

Is RL null?

Is RR null?

What about MaxRows? inc?

You haven't provided enough information to get any real help.

EDIT:

Based on your comment, ds1 needs to be initialized.